# How to test select clear button using userEvent

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am using the MUI library to make a `select` button with an added end adornment that clears the selection. Everything works great but I can't seem to figure out how to test the `clearClick` handler functionality, i.e. when clear click event is fired, the options should be cleared. How can I achieve this given this component?

```
// my-select.tsx
import * as React from 'react'
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel'
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl'
import SelectZ, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select'
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton'
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear'
import { FormHelperText } from '@mui/material'

type MenuItemProp = 'key' | 'value' | 'label'

export interface SelectProps {
  className?: string
  style?: Object

  name: string
  options: Array<Record<MenuItemProp, any>>
  defaultValue?: string
  label?: string
  formHelperText?: string | null
}

export function Select ({
  className,
  style,

  name,
  options,
  defaultValue,
  label = '',
  formHelperText = null
}: SelectProps): JSX.Element {
  const [currentOption, setCurrentOption] = React.useState(defaultValue)

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent): void => {
    setCurrentOption(event.target.value)
  }
  const handleClearClick = (): void => {
    setCurrentOption('')
  }

  return (
    <div className={className} style={style}>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel id={`${name}-select-label`}>{label}</InputLabel>
        <SelectZ
          className='select-button'
          value={currentOption ?? ''}
          label={label ?? ''}
          onChange={handleChange}
          endAdornment={<IconButton onClick={handleClearClick} sx={{ visibility: currentOption ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}> <ClearIcon /> </IconButton>}
        >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.key} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </SelectZ>
        <FormHelperText>{formHelperText}</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Select
```